# Heads and Tails of a Stack

Tags: list, stack

```
Push(A)
Push(B) 
Pop 
Pop 
Push(C) 
Push(A) 
Pop 
Push(X)
```

This would cause me to end up with this linear list:

X

C

However, how would this look as a array? Would it be stack={X,C} or stack={C,X}?

To my understanding, it would be X,C because the top of a stack is the head, and everything else is the bottom (tails), so in this case C would have to be tails and X the head, giving us X,C. Before I just accepted this however, I just thought it would be wise to get the second opinion of someone, thanks!

EDIT: I just remembered that stacks are LIFO (last in first out) structures... Which just made things more complicated for me. If the 'last one in' is the first being removed first, by that logic the array would look like C,X would it not? Since X was added to the stack last..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of implementing it would be to add new entries to the end of a vector, and remove them from the end when popping:

```
template <typename T>
class MyStack
{
public:
  void push(const T& value) { m_stack.push_back(value); }
  void pop() { m_stack.pop_back(); }

private:
  vector<T> m_stack;
};
```

Assuming the underlying `vector` looks like: `[] [] [] [] [] [] []`:

Push(A)

```
[A] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

Push(B)

```
[A] [B] [] [] [] [] []
```

Pop

```
[A] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

Pop

```
[] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

Push(C)

```
[C] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

Push(A)

```
[C] [A] [] [] [] [] []
```

Pop

```
[C] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

Push(X)

```
[C] [X] [] [] [] [] []
```

Adding to and removing from the end of a `vector` is generally pretty efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It could be either.  It would be an implementation detail of the stack.  You could even implement it using a linked list and not have an array at all.

Comment: Hm I see, I'm just worried about the chances of this coming up in a exam and it forcing me to choose between X,C or C,X

Comment: @JimmyK If you are worried about it I would talk with your teacher and see what they say.  I would hope they would be smart enough to realize that either answer is acceptable, but I know that that sometimes is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how your stack looks on every step, and let's try to visualize how the array would look like. For convenience, the first entry of the array will be the left-most entry

```
Push(A)  --> [A]
Push(B)  --> [B, A]
Pop      --> [A]
Pop      --> []
Push(C)  --> [C]
Push(A)  --> [A, C]
Pop      --> [C]
Push(X)  --> [X, C]
```

Notice that implement a stack on an array this way is a bit complicated, since you need to move all the previous items already stored in the array one position (to the right for each `push` and to the left for each `pop`).

A "thumb rule" I use is: always the first item in the stack is the one that will be popped out. In an array, the first item has the index `0` (or 1, depending on the language you use).

---

If you keep track of the index of the last entry, then things might be easier:

```
Push(A)  --> [A]      (lastIndex = 0)
Push(B)  --> [A, B]   (lastIndex = 1)
Pop      --> [A]      (lastIndex = 0)
Pop      --> []       (lastIndex = -1) # Empty stack
Push(C)  --> [C]      (lastIndex = 0)
Push(A)  --> [C, A]   (lastIndex = 1)
Pop      --> [C]      (lastIndex = 0)
Push(X)  --> [C, X]   (lastIndex = 1)
```

This is a simpler approach... the trade off is that you need to keep the `lastIndex` stored somewhere.